# Makefile macro modifier

Tags: linux, macos, build, macros, makefile

I am totally confused about the following macro modifier in a Makefile I have come onto,

```
TOOLS = $(TOOL_ROOTS:%=$(OBJDIR)%$(TOOL_SUFFIX))
```

Here

```
TOOL_ROOTS=some filename prefixes
OBJDIR=$HOME/obj/
TOOL_SUFFIX=.so
```

Can someone tell me what this line actually means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TOOL_ROOTS` must be getting assigned some value other than the empty string at some point or that does nothing (which I'll show in a moment).

So first things first just expanding the variables takes us from:

```
TOOLS = $(TOOL_ROOTS:%=$(OBJDIR)%$(TOOL_SUFFIX))
```

to:

```
TOOLS = $(:%=~/obj%.so)
```

(which we can immediately see doesn't look right, and as I'll explain in a moment doesn't do anything)

So lets pretend it has a value instead.

```
TOOL_ROOTS = shovel axe hammer
```

And try the expansion again:

```
TOOLS = $(shovel axe hammer:%=~/obj%.so)
```

(That `OBJDIR` definition looks odd also. I would expect it to be `~/obj/` or something... and that's ignoring that `~` is a bad choice here and that `$HOME` would be much better.)

The next thing we need to know is what that syntax is all about. Well it is a [Substitution Reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs).

> A substitution reference substitutes the value of a variable with alterations that you specify. It has the form ‘$(var:a=b)’ (or ‘${var:a=b}’) and its meaning is to take the value of the variable var, replace every a at the end of a word with b in that value, and substitute the resulting string.
>
> When we say “at the end of a word”, we mean that a must appear either followed by whitespace or at the end of the value in order to be replaced; other occurrences of a in the value are unaltered. For example:
>
> ```
> foo := a.o b.o c.o
> bar := $(foo:.o=.c)
> ```
>
> sets ‘bar’ to ‘a.c b.c c.c’. See Setting Variables.
>
> A substitution reference is actually an abbreviation for use of the patsubst expansion function (see Functions for String Substitution and Analysis). We provide substitution references as well as patsubst for compatibility with other implementations of make.
>
> Another type of substitution reference lets you use the full power of the patsubst function. It has the same form ‘$(var:a=b)’ described above, except that now a must contain a single ‘%’ character. This case is equivalent to ‘$(patsubst a,b,$(var))’. See Functions for String Substitution and Analysis, for a description of the patsubst function.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> foo := a.o b.o c.o
> bar := $(foo:%.o=%.c)
> ```
>
> sets ‘bar’ to ‘a.c b.c c.c’.

So, the first `%` there is matching the entirety of every word in the value of the variable (here `shovel axe hammer`) and then replacing each value with the expansion of the second part.

So `shovel` becomes `~/objshovel.so`, etc. and we end up with:

```
TOOLS = ~/objshovel.so ~/objaxe.so ~/objhammer.so
```

See what I meant about `OBJDIR` being odd before? `OBJDIR=~/obj/` would have left us with this instead:

```
TOOLS = ~/obj/shovel.so ~/obj/axe.so ~/obj/hammer.so
```

which makes a lot more sense to me.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the nice explanations. I have gone through some tutorials and still was unclear. I forgot to stick to the basics that is reading the make manual.

My bad it indeed ends with a path separator. I actually replaced the original path witha sample path and forgot to put the "/",
I think TOOL_ROOTS is defined elsewhere in included files or rues files.

Comment: can you please tell me what this actually means, "$(SA_TOOLS:%=%$(OBJ_SUFFIX)): %: | dir"
OBJ_SUFFIX=.o

I know it will replace everything in SA_TOOLS with OBJ_SUFFIX added, but whats about :%:| dir, why there is a rule as a source? I know what every other prerequisites do, but it seems to me here a rool is defined as target.
here dir just simply makes a directory

Comment: That (the `a : b: c` syntax) is a [Static Pattern Rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) though with that formulation it doesn't serve much purpose over just using a normal rule. The `| dir` bit is an [`order-only` prerequisite](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) and yes `dir` is a (likely `.PHONY`) target used to make sure the output directory (I assume) exists.

Comment: Thanks these are making sense to me now.